# Setting Date depending on column in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I want to set a Date depending on the value of the Column `sourcename`.

I have a Dataframe like this

```
sourcename date  
2008       2020-12-12  
2009       2020-12-12  
2010       2020-12-12  
2012       2020-12-12
```

I tried the following

```
df['date'] = datetime(df['Sourcename'].str[0:4].astype(int),1,1,0,0,1)
```

But i keep on get this error:
TypeError: cannot convert the series to `<class 'int'>`

Comment: What mean `,1,1,0,0,1` ?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: the Part ```,1,1,0,0,1``` is that i pass the values for the month, day, hour,minutes,and second

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the rows of your dataframe with [df.itertuples()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.itertuples.html) (see below). Then, with each row tuple, you can access the value of each column.

For example, you can use `row.sourcename` to access the value of the column `sourcename` for that particular row. There is also a `row.Index` property to access the index of the row.

To modify the value of a column, you can use [df.loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html?highlight=loc#pandas.DataFrame.loc) with the index of the row and the name of the column to modify.

```py
for row in df.itertuples():
        df.loc[row.Index, 'date'] = str(datetime(int(row.sourcename), 1, 1, 0, 0, 1))
```

Then if we display `df`:

```
    sourcename  date
0   2008        2008-01-01 00:00:01
1   2009        2009-01-01 00:00:01
2   2010        2010-01-01 00:00:01
3   2012        2012-01-01 00:00:01
```